# Django daphne asgi: Django can only handle ASGI/HTTP connections, not websocket

Tags: django, daphne, asgi

This is really frustrating, I did set everything up according to the documentation, but daphne keeps throwing an error when I try to run it independently, it does work correctly when I use `python manage.py run server`. this is very frustrating and I can't seem to find similar error anywhere else

```
2020-01-25 09:57:17,627 INFO     Starting server at tcp:port=8000:interface=127.0.0.1
2020-01-25 09:57:17,628 INFO     HTTP/2 support not enabled (install the http2 and tls Twisted extras)
2020-01-25 09:57:17,628 INFO     Configuring endpoint tcp:port=8000:interface=127.0.0.1
2020-01-25 09:57:17,629 INFO     Listening on TCP address 127.0.0.1:8000
127.0.0.1:44516 - - [25/Jan/2020:09:57:27] "WSCONNECTING /ws/score/" - -
2020-01-25 09:57:28,637 ERROR    Exception inside application: Django can only handle ASGI/HTTP connections, not websocket.
  File "/home/sofdeath/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/daphne/cli.py", line 30, in asgi
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/sofdeath/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/asgi.py", line 146, in __call__
    % scope['type']
  Django can only handle ASGI/HTTP connections, not websocket.
127.0.0.1:44516 - - [25/Jan/2020:09:57:28] "WSDISCONNECT /ws/score/" - -
^C2020-01-25 09:57:39,126 INFO     Killed 0 pending application instances
```

here is my asgi.py

```
import os

from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'tabulator.settings')

application = get_asgi_application()
```

my routing.py:

```
from django.urls import re_path
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator, OriginValidator
import judge.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(
                judge.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
            )
        )
    ),
})
```

and in my settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'channels',
]
...
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'tabulator.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = "tabulator.routing.application"
...
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [('127.0.0.1', 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 37):

change your `asgi.py` to this:

```
import os
import django
from channels.routing import get_default_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'tabulator.settings')

django.setup()

application = get_default_application()
```

Comment: Oh, that actually worked. I initially thought it didn't, because I didn't see that it also changed `from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application` to `from channels.routing import get_default_application` wrt the tutorial. Note to other reader: This was taken from [the Channels deployment guide](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html).

Comment: @ahmadgh74 WOW!

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your asgi.py according to [this](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/part_2.html)

```
# mysite/asgi.py
import os

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
import chat.routing

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
  "http": get_asgi_application(),
  "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

Comment: This should be voted as the new and up-to-date solution as at the 6th of Feb, 2023

Answer (score -1):

change your `asgi.py` as @ahmad says and edit your `settings.py` to this:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            "hosts": [("redis", 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

and be sure that `DEBUG = False`. That is because you are not running your project on local server it it will throw an error if you use `"127.0.0.1"` or `"localhost"`.